# UIButton delay & weird toolbar behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have the following situation:

```
[viewController.view addSubview:_tableView];
[viewController.view addSubview:_footerBar]; // _footerBar is a UIToolbar so I 
                                             // get a blur-effect for free
[_footerBar addSubview:_myButton];
```

[image]

But there's a problem with the UIButton: When it's tapped it takes .5 seconds until it changes its appearance to highlighted.

Here's some attempts to fix it:

**IDEA 1:**

However, it was not the case when I positioned the footer above the _tableView header! Which led to another discovery: The highlighted state comes immediately IF I assign the frame of the footer after it has been added to the parent.

Delayed highlight case (BAD USER EXPERIENCE):

```
CGRect footerFrame = CGRectMake(...)
_footerBar = [[UIToolBar alloc] initWithFrame:footerFrame];
[self.view addSubview:_footerBar];
// add button(s) here..
```

Immediate highlight (GOOD USER EXPERIENCE):

```
CGRect footerFrame = CGRectMake(...)
_footerBar = [[UIToolBar alloc] initWithFrame:footerFrame];
[self.view addSubview:_footerBar];
_footerBar.frame = footerFrame; // just assigning it again helps!
// add button(s) here..
```

-> Didn't work reliably after all.

**IDEA 2:**

Subclass UITableView and reduce hit-area.

-> Didn't work

**IDEA 3:**

Add Buttons as subviews of viewController.view instead of _footerBar

-> Didn't work either.

**IDEA 4:**

Try different UIButton-types.

-> Didn't help.

Any idea what is going on here? I'd like to have immediate highlighting, but I want it to be clean and understood..

I'm talking about iOS7 here, by the way.

Comment: Are you seeing this behaviour in the simulator, or a device or both ?

Comment: Can you give us code which you have written on buttons tap event?

Comment: @Ohnomycoco: Problem is on device, not in simulator.

Comment: Maybe you are blocking main thread for 0.5 sec by doing something on tap? Then it could explain this delay.

Comment: @Fedorov Nope. Even if I comment out everything in the handler it still shows the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, case closed.

The problem is the position of the buttons. It's at the bottom of the screen. I assume iOS7 waits to decide if the tap isn't in fact a tap to open Control Center.

If I switch the app to full screen the behaviour is different and the problem doesn't appear.